# My jQuery Cookie Not Working On DIV hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

So I have this function to close a message alert (pop-up model). That works as it should. very simple jQuery. However, I'm trying to add a cookie that when a user closes the pop-up model, if they visit the page again within the same session, the model won't pop-up again. I want the cookie to expire or delete after browser close. Can't get it to work though...What am I doing wrong?

I'm using this script:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

```
// Update Prompt: Hide on 'X' click
function setsomecookie(){ // adds cookie 1 day
    $.cookie('message_prompt', 'prompt_closed');
}    
$('.updateCloseBTN').click(function () {
    $('.upgradeWrap').fadeOut(400, setsomecookie);
});
```

Comment: Hey, It's you again! Whats your code to read the cookie?

Comment: Your definitely setting it right, I think the problem is when it is compared

Comment: I'm bacccckkk lol. Yeah, it's driving me nuts. Compared...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the '#message_alert_box' set to {display:none;} in your .css

Then, when the user goes from page to page, you need to verify if the cookie has a specific value

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    if($.cookie('message_prompt') != 'prompt_closed') {

        $('#message_alert_box').show(); // If the cookie isn't set to 'prompt_close' , then show the alert box

    }

});
```

Comment: Okay, so just add this to the same js file? (it's loaded on every page)

Comment: Sounds good. Let me test...display:none of course! Already there. FadeOut() wouldn't function without.  ;)

Comment: Fixed! I saw my problem! Even after using your code. it still wasn't working. But that was only because I had a separate slideDown()_ functional that was overriding this cookie. All works now! Thanks a bunch for your help! I understand this cookie stuff now. :)

Comment: Awesome! what version a jquery are you using?

Comment: I was only asking because I was doing a test of my own and script kept breaking, I thought maybe the plugin wasn't compatible with the newest version.  Turns out my include to the cookie script was a line below the </head> ... haha, I love dumb mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your document is wrapped in the `document.ready()` function.

```
$(document).ready(
   //all body code within here. 
});
```

Comment: Already have that man...I got the basics of jQuery down. This function is running in a document ready js file that has some other functions in it. Let's not focus on that. ;)